Probability measures on $\mathbb{N}$
It's intuitively obvious that all probability measures on $\mathbb{N}$ are given by $P( \{k \}) = p_k \geq 0 $ with $\sum p_k =1 $ and $P(A) = \sum \limits_{k \in A} p_k$. But how do I prove that it is sigma-additive?
For $A = A_1 \sqcup A_2 \ldots \sqcup A_m    $ I can refer to the fact that the sum of absolutely convergent series doesn't depend on the order of summands. But what do I do if $\bigsqcup \limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i $?

Your $P$ is $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}p_k\delta_{k}$, which is a countable sum of measures, so $P$ is a measure.

Hints: Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $N$ such that $ \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty}p_k <\epsilon$.
Let $B_i=\{1,2,....,N\}\cap A_i$. These are disjoint subsets of $\{1,2,....,N\}$. Hence there can only be finite number of non-empty sets among these. Suppose $B_i=\emptyset$ for $i >M$.
Now $P(\cup_i A_i)\le P(\cup_i A_i)\cap \{1,2,....,N\})+\epsilon=P(\cup_i B_i)+\epsilon$ (Why?).
And $P(\cup_i B_i)=P(\cup_{i \le M} B_i)=\sum_{i \le M}P(B_i)\le \sum P(A_i)$.
Conclude now that $P(\cup_i A_i)\le \sum P(A_i)$.
But $P(\cup_i A_i)\ge P(\cup_{i\le k} A_i)=\sum_{i \le k} P(A_i)$ for al $k$ Let $k \to \infty$ to get $P(\cup_i A_i)\ge \sum P(A_i)$. .
